# How much lead is there in the universe?

Tags: universe, atoms, estimation, elements

I know there is around $10^{80}$ atoms in the observable universe, but is there any estimate the amount of lead in the universe (within a couple magnitudes of $10$)?

Comment: Are you worried about being poisoned?

Comment: No, actually, I am wondering whether the amount of lead is merely small (less than 1 / 10^3) or vanishingly rare (less than 1 / 10^60)

Comment: [The estimated fraction of lead atoms in the universe](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=atomic+abundance+of+lead) is $6\cdot10^{-11}$.

Comment: @mmc: why not post as an answer? Also: does this belong on [astronomy.SE]?

Comment: @David Zaslavsky I feel certain resistance to post very short answers and I often don't have enough time for writing more proper ones :-) I also think that Astronomy.SE is the most appropriate site.

Comment: @mmc: fair enough, I understand the reluctance to post a very short answer... but I think that if you have an answer, as long as it really does answer the question, even if it is very short, it's better to post it as an answer than as a comment.

Comment: I've asked in the astronomy chat room whether they want this question, just to be sure, but with mmc and myself in agreement I'm inclined to say it should go there. I'm not supposed to migrate questions to beta sites, but donnyton, perhaps you could just re-ask this question at [astronomy.SE] and I can close this one?

Comment: Well, I certainly got the answer I wanted, so this question's over...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The estimated fraction of lead atoms in the universe](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=atomic+abundance+of+lead) is $6 \times 10^{−11}$.

Comment: Alpha is only giving molar abundance, not atomic abundance.  Link rot?